# TF predict multiple predictions at once

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, tf.keras

I am trying to batch predict a number of inputs to my model which expects an input containing 2 1D lists of a fixed size like this:

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 150), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[2,  924, ...]])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 150), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[2,  130, ...]])>]
```

Assuming this input is called input_in, I can predict a sample by writing:

```
transformer.predict(input_in)
```

Where input_in thus has the following shape:

> (2, 1, 150)

And this works. However, I can't understand the input necessary to pass to predict() to predict multiple predictions at once. Intuitively, the shape has to be something like this:

> (X, 2, 1, 150)

Where X is the number of predictions to pass.

I tried this, but I receive an error:

```
transformer.predict([input_in, input_in, input_in])

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1801, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1783, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 200, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Layer "{layer_name}" expects {len(input_spec)} input(s),'

    ValueError: Layer "transformer" expects 2 input(s), but it received 6 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 12) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, 12) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4' shape=(None, 12) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>]
```

Interestingly, if I try to predict one input but simply change the input to a tensor, I also get a similar error:

```
transformer_test.predict(tf.convert_to_tensor([input_tensor,output_tensor]))


-> ValueError: Layer "transformer" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 1, 150) dtype=int64>]
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
My Transformer model looks like this:

[image]

**I also reproduced a minimal version of the issue: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xYNjLURQcGPIXeWV-xo4_iA09KDJvNfi?usp=sharing**

If you run all, the last 2 cells will give errors. I have been trying to play around with the input to batch predict but nothing seems to have worked...

Comment: This means that your input_ids are all different shape, did you pass your input to the tokenizer to standardise it?

Comment: @EdwinCheong you're right, fixed, now they are all padded to the same length. However I still don't know the shape necessary for this and still get the same error... I edited the question now

Comment: @Kurt what's your `transformer` model? also what's the full stacktrace of the error you're getting?

Comment: @thushv89 updated the question with a screenshot of model.summary() (due to formatting purposes) and the full stack trace... Hope that's ok :)

Comment: I have also updated the question to include a colab link showcasing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try using the names of your input layers as references:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.stack([batch_inputs[0], batch_inputs[0], batch_inputs[0]]))).map(lambda x: {'inputs': x[0], "dec_inputs": x[1]})
predictions = transformer_test.predict(ds)
```

And without `tf.stack`:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((batch_inputs)).map(lambda x: {'inputs': x[0], "dec_inputs": x[1]})
```

Comment: Thank you!! This actually solves the issue. The thing I was missing was the references. Appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing missing is how to set the batch size for this, as after setting .batch(2) after/before the map, I face the following error as a new dimension is created:

Input 0 of layer "encoder_layer_0" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, None, 512), found shape=(None, 1, 128, 512)

Answer (score 2):

Im no expert but you could try stacking your multiple inputs(input_in) with tf.stack instead of passing them in as a list.

transformer.predict (tf.stack([input_tensor, input_tensor, input_tensor]))

thats my best guess

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried on the colab link posted in the question but I got a similar error:  `ValueError: Layer "transformer" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 2, 1, 128) dtype=int64>]`